# PowerBI, Live connection to Bigquery is slow, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I am connecting PowerBI to Bigquery view, it is slow, how to troubleshoot and understand if it PowerBI or Bigquery, I use the same view in datastudio and it is way faster.

I attached an example here

https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNTg5MDVjYjktZmNjMi00MzJjLWEzY2UtMTJmMTllNzI3ZTk2IiwidCI6IjdmNjhjN2QwLTc0ZTgtNGE2Ni04NGI3LWZhMjdlMzYyNTFiOCJ9

in the console, I get this results

Query complete (1.5 sec elapsed, 8.4 MB processed)

I know there is an overhead to download the data from BQ to PowerBI, but it seems very slow for such a small data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refresh this report from within Power BI Desktop with [Performance Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-performance-analyzer) recording session, which should give you better understanding what is going on, where, and how long it takes:

[image]

You could also use [DAX Studio](https://daxstudio.org/) to [capture the queries](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/analyze-directquery-requests-using-dax-studio/) sent to the data source, if you believe that they are slow:

[image]